# How to make a path to a directory non-specific in Java?

Tags: java, path, directory

I am using a KeyStore-class in Java. I am using a .load method to input a file to the KeyStore. Basically, I have a KeyStore KS and use:

```
KS.load("C:\\users\\camp-nto\\dc16-signing\\src\\main\\resources\\kontaktinfo-client-test.jks")
```

However, this will obliviously just work on my computer. If someone else uses the class, they get an error because the file "kontaktinfo-client-tests.jks" is in a different folder.

Is there any way to make this work on other computers? To make a more "generic"-path, or something like that.

Thank you!

Comment: put the file in the classpath and read it from there

Comment: You could deliver it within your application or use "user.home" for example

Comment: Thank you! It helped putting it to the classpath. Amd Henning, thank you for your answer as well. I can try that next time.